# Cannot sign in Mi account after MIUI 12 update on Redmi Note 8

Tags: miui-12

[image]

Recently I updated my Redmi Note 8 to the MIUI. Since then, I get this notification.
I've tried "signing in" again but it doesn't work.
Also can't sign in more than one google account anywhere on the device.

Help!

Comment: remove the bonding and add the account again